# Is it possible to delete all but duplicate rows with PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel, duplicates

I'm trying to find a way to delete all BUT the repeated rows in a file, I know it's possible to delete the duplicates on a file using something like this:

```
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex();
    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator($rowIndex + 1) as $testRow) {
        if ($testRow == $row) {
            $worksheet->removeRow($rowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

However I need to do pretty much the opposite, delete all the rows that doesn't have any duplicates in the file.

**Why do I need this**: The duplicate rows are the intersection between M x M sets with data. It's way easier to do it directly on the file that having to considerate the M x M possible results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this function removes unique values from chosen **column**:

```
function removeUniqueRows($objPHPExcel, $column = 'A') {
    $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $cells = array();

    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex();
        $cellValue = $worksheet->getCell($column.$rowIndex)->getValue();
        array_push($cells, $cellValue);       
    }

    $toRemove = array_keys(array_diff($cells, array_diff_assoc($cells, array_unique($cells))));

    for ($i = count($toRemove)-1; $i > -1; $i--) {
        $worksheet->removeRow($toRemove[$i]+1);
    }

    return $objPHPExcel;
}
```

If you need to remove rows basing on values in many columns, you can easily modify this code to concatenate cell values into one or maybe work directly on whole rows (I don't know if this is possible in PHPExcel, I didn't try it).

**UPDATE:**

Here you have two functions. One is for removing duplicated rows (leaving only one for each set of duplicates) and second one is for removing all unique rows (completely). Both these functions can take as argument snigle column leter **or an array of column letters** and use it to filter rows.

First function:

```
function removeDuplicateRows($objPHPExcel, $columns = 'A', $separator = '|') {
    $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $cells = array();

    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex();
        if (is_array($columns)) {
            $cellValue = '';
            foreach ($columns as $column) {
                $cellValue .= $worksheet->getCell($column.$rowIndex)->getValue() . $separator;
            }
        } else {
            $cellValue = $worksheet->getCell($columns.$rowIndex)->getValue();
        }
        array_push($cells, $cellValue);       
    }

    $toRemove = array_keys(array_diff_assoc($cells, array_unique($cells)));

    for ($i = count($toRemove)-1; $i > -1; $i--) {
        $worksheet->removeRow($toRemove[$i]+1);
    }

    return $objPHPExcel;
}
```

Second function:

```
function removeUniqueRows($objPHPExcel, $columns = 'A', $separator = '|') {
    $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $cells = array();

    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex();
        if (is_array($columns)) {
            $cellValue = '';
            foreach ($columns as $column) {
                $cellValue .= $worksheet->getCell($column.$rowIndex)->getValue() . $separator;
            }
        } else {
            $cellValue = $worksheet->getCell($columns.$rowIndex)->getValue();
        }
        array_push($cells, $cellValue);       
    }

    $toRemove = array_keys(array_diff($cells, array_diff_assoc($cells, array_unique($cells))));

    for ($i = count($toRemove)-1; $i > -1; $i--) {
        $worksheet->removeRow($toRemove[$i]+1);
    }

    return $objPHPExcel;
}
```

If I correctly understood what you need, then you have to do something similar to:

```
$columns = array('A', 'B', 'G', 'H');
removeDuplicateRows(removeUniqueRows($objPHPExcel, $columns), $columns);
```

Comment: Hi. I did this slightly different, the problem now is PHPExcel doesn't reaccomodate the rows. It just leaves the empty rows where the info was deleted. It doens't have the feature yet.

Comment: @Splendonia, I'm using PHPExcel 1.8.0 and it **does** reaccomodate the rows. Just checked.

Comment: After deleting all but the duplicated rows, I need to leave only one of each duplicated rows, however, when I do removeRow, it just leaves the row blank and I'm pretty sure I'm using 1.8.0 too.

Comment: @Splendonia, OK, lets try to figure it out. You wrote that you 'slightly different'. How different exactly? What did you change?

Comment: More like completely different. I took the code I posted above when made the question as an starting point. This is the code I have. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b8046ff7847d497cb194

Comment: @Splendonia, well your code looks very different to mine. I updated my answer with extended code which should help you. I didn't extensively test it, but it worked on some simple excel sheets.

Comment: They both work wonderfully separated however. When I run them together, the 'duplicated rows' method seems to be deleting all the duplicated rows which are the result of applying 'RemoveUnique' instead of leaving just one. I'm working on it to see if I can make it work.

Comment: @Splendonia, if you find any error in my code, then write a comment here. Also, always check your data. Those function should work in combination without error - maybe your data isn't correct or you didn't use proper columns?

Comment: @Splendonia, also, if your data contains `|` then you should change `$separator` to something else.

Comment: The only problem I've been encountering it's that when it comes to deleting duplicates, it deletes all of them, instead of leaving one of each element that has duplicates.

Comment: @Splendonia, maybe we try from the start. So, when you use `removeUniqueRows` on your Excel file, are all unique rows removed? Try to create file with removed unique rows and check if there is everything OK. Then, use `removeDuplicateRows` on this new file.

Comment: @Splendonia, is this possible for you, to post your excel file somewhere and write which columns should be used do firstly remove unique rows and then remove duplicates? I'd like to test it myself.

Comment: The files are in here https://www.dropbox.com/s/9lvy4u5oftsx5q5/xls.rar. The original file, the outputs when I apply each one and the desired results. When I apply both like you told me, it returns an empty file just the header row no info

Comment: @Splendonia, I've checked and files are processed properly. Everything what should be removed is correctly removed and there are four rows in result XLSX - just like in your `desired-result.xlsx` (except the header row). In my code all I've done was `$objPHPExcel = removeDuplicateRows(removeUniqueRows($objPHPExcel, $columns), $columns);` (where `$columns = array('A', 'B', 'G', 'H');`) and everythind was processed successfully. Do you have the same in you code? Especially, do you update `$objPHPExcel` with result from removeDuplicateRows and removeUniqueRows?

Comment: I do `$columns = array('A', 'B', 'G', 'H');      $ObjPHPExcel = $this->removeDuplicateRows($this->removeUniqueRows($phpExcelObject, $columns), $columns);` and `$writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($ObjPHPExcel, 'Excel5');` but i get an empty file

Comment: And are you *completely* sure that `$phpExcelObject` contains your workbook? You didn't misspell variable name?

Comment: Completely sure, if I don't use the functions I get 'no-remove', I'm doing  `$readerObject = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
        $phpExcelObject = $readerObject->load('files/downloads/reports/' . $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getName() . '.xls');`

Comment: @Splendonia, this is my code: http://pastebin.com/cj3mg23u . It works - I've checked it. Try it yourself and tell me if it works for you. You need to run it in the same folder as `no-remove.xls` and it will produce `after-remove.xlsx`. You may also need to modify `include`s at the top of the code.

Comment: Do not worry about `ob_clean();` - it's a leftover from old code. It doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Hi! I tried it, it wasn't the code, it was the way I was applying the code. I had the whole write to xls on a loop, and I was applying the code on each iteration instead of applying it on the final result, that's why It wasn't working. This is a random question, but what would I need to restrict the removing the duplicate rows besides the columns to the number of appareances of each item? Thank you for your dedication to this question, seriously admirable.

Comment: @Splendonia, give me example of such restriction. For example, you have four rows with 'ABC' inside and you want to remove all duplicates except first two or three? This can be easily done by adding one additonal parameter to `removeDuplicateRows` and doing some internal counter. Tell me if this is what you've meant. And about dedication - Stack Overflow is about helping each other. Its nice to make someone bit happier :-)

Comment: Example: I have Site1 repeated on rows 1,2,3,4. Site 2 repeated on 5, 6, Site4 7,8,9, could I only delete the sites that have <4 repeats? Meaning, All repeats for Site 2 and Site 4 would be deleted and only one row of Site1 would show up? In other words, Delete all rows that don't have less than X number of duplicates.

Comment: @Splendonia, try this code: http://pastebin.com/yV9sh8qc . I tested it on XLSX file with rows that you described and it worked good. You should set `$maxNumRemovals` to maximum number of rows from given duplicate set that should be removed.

Comment: Grzegorz once again thank you so much for your help, you're an angel!